# Reduce map copyright text

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, copyright

I am using leaflet map. I have copied the map text from one of it's example.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
    attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, TomTom, Intermap, iPC, USGS, FAO, NPS, NRCAN, GeoBase, Kadaster NL, Ordnance Survey, Esri Japan, METI, Esri China (Hong Kong), and the GIS User Community',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Is it legal to reduce copyright text ?

**Current copyright text**
[image: Logn copy right text]
Tiles © Esri — Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, TomTom, Intermap, iPC, USGS, FAO, NPS, NRCAN, GeoBase, Kadaster NL, Ordnance Survey, Esri Japan, METI, Esri China (Hong Kong), and the GIS User Community

**I want to change it to**

© OpenStreetMap contributors

[image: Short copyright text]

**Edit**

I have udpated the map tile provider to openstreet maps.

**Reference** - http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the copyright of the tiles that you are displaying in the layer to which the attribution applies.  If that's your own map tiles in a style that is entirely your own, then your proposed change would be fine.  If you're still planning to display Mapbox Streets, then I wouldn't expect that it would be (though IANAL of course).

Comment: Where can I get more information about it ? you can check my tiles link in the code ? it states mapbox.com

Comment: Could you share a reference?

Comment: You'll need to ask Mapbox what the "minimal attribution" for one of the tile styles is, but as it's included in their example, I'm guessing that the attribution used in your example is there for a reason.  There are a bunch of links on https://www.mapbox.com/contact/ - I'd start there.

Comment: So is the attribution related to style or to data? Your answer mixes the two and you don't provide any evidence for either one.

Comment: For both. If you want to shorten the copyright text then switch to a style (i.e. tile server) that requires a shorter attribution. Or render your own tiles in which case you just have to show the copyright for the map data.

Comment: I have updated the map provider ? is it possible to reduce copyright text now ?

Comment: Which tile server are you using now exactly?

Comment: @scai - it is in the question. To be specific - http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer

Comment: No. You have to provide the full copyright text as specified by the tile provider you are using. If ESRI also has such a long copyright text then you are not allowed to shorten it.